# Flash upload image resize client side

Tags: flash, image-processing, upload

Does anyone got an ideia on how to get client side image resize using flash.

Example:
Client chooses an image with 1200x800 and before it uploads it flash will turn it into half of it or something.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Plupload is Opensource, has good documentation and supports multiple platforms, including Gears and HTML5!

http://www.plupload.com/index.php
http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php

Ah, yes, it supports resizing images BEFORE uploading. The closest option to aurigma, but for free :)

Comment: I _heard_ that the quality of resized image is not good though, then what's the use!

Comment: It is Open Source, so you can always improve it. i.e: compile imagemagick with Emscripten and you will get tons of options to improve image quality.

Answer (score 10):

take a look at the script i wrote : 
[image resizing at client side](http://www.adylevy.com/index.php/2009/06/07/client-side-image-resize-flash-cs4-filereferencedata/)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

I just finished this little project - free to use. It won't really allow the end user to select the size, but you can pass a max width and max height constraint. Maybe you can make multiple pages/embeds with different options.

Comment: This project is no longer active, though is open source. It does however convert all images to JPG files on upload. A problem if you want to upload line-art type PNG files (as the quality is dramatically affected).

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight, ActiveX and Java can do this completely client-side. If you have to use Flash you are going to need to use Flash 10 which isn't prevalent quite yet. Here is an example on [uploading an image to Flash then resizing it on the client](http://flexgraphix.com/blog/?p=51) from Flash Cafe.

Other options in Flash 8 or 9 would involve a server-side resizing script, defeating the purpose in most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You need create a transformation matrix, then draw the original bitmap into a new one using it. Here's the idea in something i am just typing in and have not tested:

```
function resize(obm:BitmapData, scale:Number): BitmapData {
   var resizeMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
   resizeMatrix.scale(scale, scale);

   var rbm:BitmapData = new BitmapData(obm.width * scale, obm.height * scale);
   rbm.draw(obm, resizeMatrix);

   return rbm;
}
```

I make no claims about the quality of the result, however. I think I remember trying this in the past, not liking the result, and punting...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using flash uploader from http://www.resize-before-upload.com, works just fine :)

Comment: This is no longer supported and will not allow BMP files to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of **SwfUpload** does client-side image resizing (using Flash).  A pretty useful tool, although extras like displaying upload progress can get a little fiddly.

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: It looks as though the project may be dead. It hasn't been updated since March 2010, v2.5 is a 'beta 3' and there are a number of open issues - see http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/issues/list.