# What's a good client-side, resize-before-upload, flash/java uploader?

Tags: java, flash, image, upload

does anybody know a good client-side, resize-before-upload, flash/java uploader?

We need this terribly on our project, since we have a lot of people uploading photos and most of them have photos which are bigger than 3MB. We want to be able to resize these photos before they get sent out to us.

I've googled for client-side java/flash uploaders, but I wasn't impressed with the results.

Is there anyone here who has already purchased a java/flash uploader before? Which ones are good?

Thanks!

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431120/flash-upload-image-resize-client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

I just finished this little project. It's a very tricky thing to do - resizing before uploading and then to make matters worse there's a few gotchas. Such as if you wanted to use a submit button outside of Flash (via ExternalInterface) to submit... You could end up in some trouble. I released my project for free and it should take away all the headaches for ya. Though it's only a single file upload (some other projects like swfupload and plupload aim to provide multiple file uploading but are much larger projects and I feel too bulky and take too long to setup on top of the fact that they really aren't that seamless, you'll be jumping through hoops on the backend).

Comment: Sadly this project is no longer supported. Good: it's on github. Not so good: it converts png and gif source files to jpg with some undesirable results; it can't resize bitmaps; it has a few bugs.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.plupload.com/ 
Allows you to upload files using HTML5 Gears, Silverlight, Flash, BrowserPlus or normal forms, providing some unique features such as upload progress, image resizing and chunked uploads.

Comment: For those that need to be able to resize gif or bmp files, plupload.com can currently only resize jpg and png files (not gif or bmp files).