# jquery + flash: looking for plugin that resize images before upload

Tags: jquery, flash, upload, resize

i'm looking for a jquery plugin that can upload multiple images.
I've tried uploadify and it works well.

But with huge images it's very slow.

is There  anything like uploadify that resize also the images before upload them?

thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431120/flash-upload-image-resize-client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://www.plupload.com/

Demo http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php

It was just released a few days ago (3rd Feb) and has the functionality you are looking for (Client-side resizing and chunking specifically can both improve performance).

It's core isn't based on jQuery, but it has a jQuery upload widget that's plug-and-play.

Comment: I _heard_ that the quality of resized image is not good though, then what's the use

Answer (score 1):

http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

Won't dictate your design, very flexible. Does not do multiple files (yet), though you can post multiple times from the same page w/o re-directing the user anywhere. It has a lot of options. Again, it's designed to fit into your design, so here's a demo that barely lets you know it's done with Flash because of all the JavaScript integration it has: http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/advanced-demo.html

For use with any back-end language.

Answer (score 1):

Use Flajaxian, its free and works with S3

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of **SwfUpload** does client-side image resizing (using Flash), but it's not the easiest script to use.

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

Comment: +1 Took me 4 hours to replace my Uploadify with SwfUpload to support client-side image resize. It supports callback functions, pretty powerful. But you have to fiddle with the javascript etc, and they're not neat (Uploadify is very neat).

Answer (score -1):

There is Uploadify image resize before upload extension. Check http://perfectwebtutorials.com/2012/image-resize-before-upload-uploadify/

Comment: This link doesn't work and has many intermediate redirects, sketchy.