# how to compress images with asp.net with out lose of qualityof image

Tags: c#

I have to  upload multiple images using java-script. so i need to compress those images without loose of image Quality.

I have to store all images in phyisical folder"uploads".

```
HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++) {
    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0) {
        hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/") +System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
    }
}
```

So i need to compress the images without loose of image Quality while uploading in physical folder

Comment: What kind of images? If they are jpegs they are already compressed.

Comment: Since, you are uploading the images. It would be better, if you could compress the images on the client side via some JQuery plugin... See this for client side compression (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579193/uploadify-and-image-compression)

Comment: Most image formats are already compressed.  Compressing them further *and* maintaining quality is only possible in the Law & Order crime labs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting the images to PNG and then using the built in ZIP compression.

```
public static void SaveToPNG(Bitmap SourceImage, string DestinationPath)
{
    SourceImage.Save(DestinationPath, ImageFormat.Png);
    CompressFile(DestinationPath, true);
}

private static string CompressFile(string SourceFile, bool DeleteSourceFile)
{
    string TargetZipFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(SourceFile, ".zip");

    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(TargetZipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(SourceFile, Path.GetFileName(SourceFile),CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }

    if(DeleteSourceFile == true)
    {
        File.Delete(SourceFile);
    }
    return TargetZipFileName;
}
```

OR your if you do not mind a little unnoticable loss, then you could convert to a JPG at a high quality and then ZIP that.  At 100% quality, your users will likely not notice any difference and the lower quality you go, the smaller the images will get, but that defeats your "without loss of quality" condition.

```
private static ImageCodecInfo __JPEGCodecInfo = null;
private static ImageCodecInfo _JPEGCodecInfo
{
    get
    {
        if (__JPEGCodecInfo == null)
        {
            __JPEGCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().ToList().Find(delegate (ImageCodecInfo codec) { return codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid; });
        }
        return __JPEGCodecInfo;
    }
}
public static void SaveToJPEG(Bitmap SourceImage, string DestinationPath, long Quality)
{
    EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, Quality);

    SourceImage.Save(DestinationPath, _JPEGCodecInfo, parameters);

    CompressFile(DestinationPath, true);
}

private static string CompressFile(string SourceFile, bool DeleteSourceFile)
{
    string TargetZipFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(SourceFile, ".zip");

    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(TargetZipFileName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(SourceFile, Path.GetFileName(SourceFile),CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    }

    if(DeleteSourceFile == true)
    {
        File.Delete(SourceFile);
    }
    return TargetZipFileName;
}
```