# Image resize (client side)

Tags: web-services, printing, jpeg, photo

I own web photo print service, main problem is that pictures users upload are twice in size (megabytes) than those I need to print them in standard photo size. Bandwidth and disk space is not a problem, what IS a problem is time it takes to upload them (for user).

If photo from camera is 2-3MB I wish to resize them somehow in half to about 1-1.5MB, that means it will upload 2x faster. Is this possible and with what technology? JAVA maybe? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Flash allows for file access without requiring a "would you like to run this untrusted code" nagbox; IIRC Facebook has a Flash photo uploader. I think Java may also support this, but Flash is a bit more ubiquitous.

Comment: Can Flash resize pictures on the fly (before actual upload process)?
I already have AJAX upload solution, problem is unnecessary filesize.
Desktop software is beating web software in this just because it is faster to send pictures, nothing else. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431120/flash-upload-image-resize-client-side for resizing on upload in Flash (I have not used/tested it). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

but only with flash player 10 or newer, it's possible to load user selected local data into flash before uploading it to the server. the image can then be manipulated client side.